# How to pass values to an ansible target

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-template

I have this inventory file

```
[app:children]
CL
#BA
#EA
#EB
#EI

[BA]
TEST-cl1 ansible_user=ec2-user modulename=BA

[CL]
TEST-cl1 ansible_user=ec2-user modulename=CL
TEST-cl1 ansible_user=ec2-user modulename=CL
TEST-cl1 ansible_user=ec2-user modulename=CL

[EA]
TEST-cl1 ansible_user=ec2-user modulename=EA

[EB]
TEST-cl1 ansible_user=ec2-user modulename=EB

[EI]
TEST-cl1 ansible_user=ec2-user modulename=EI
```

Assume my playbook is like this:

```
---
- name: RUNNING DEPLOYMENT TASKS
  hosts: app
  connection: ssh
  gather_facts: no
  remote_user: ec2-user
  tasks:
    - name: print visit particulars
      shell: echo {{ modulename }} >> f
```

What will the file "f" contain?

I would like to see "CL" as all but CL is commented off in that app group. However I see EI which I find quite disappointing (do you get why?)

Since I specify hosts: app in my playbook I thought that the children under app will be selected. Why isn't this so, and how should I code it so that I control where the task is run?

Answer (score 1):

> ***What will the file `f` contain?***

Just test with [`debug` module – Print statements during execution](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/debug_module.html).

> ***Since I specify `hosts: app` in my playbook I thought that the children under `app` will be selected.***

Right, that's the case.

A minimal example with an inventory file of **`example.com`**

```ini
[BA]
ba.example.com modulename=BA

[CL]
cl.example.com modulename=CL

[app:children]
CL
```

and a playbook **`modulename.yml`**

```yaml
---
- hosts: app
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - debug:
      msg: |
        "modulename: {{ modulename }}"
        "group_names: {{ group_names }}"
```

called via

```bash
ansible-playbook --inventory example.com modulename.yml
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [debug] *********************
ok: [cl.example.com] =>
  msg: |-
    "modulename: CL"
    "group_names: [u'CL', u'app']"
```

> ***How should I code it so that I control where the task is run?***

You may have another look under [How to build your inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_inventory.html), especially [Inventory basics: formats, hosts, and groups](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_inventory.html#inventory-basics-formats-hosts-and-groups).

Comment: I see that a difference between your example and mine is the leaf children are different in your example. So I work around my issue by having different alias for each leaf entry even though they point to the same machine. This partially overcomes the problem, though not quite what I want